# Should I use "none" or "no one" in the following sentence?

Tags: pronouns, fused-determiner

> I didn't know much about him---just that he was the president of this
>   weird club my classmates were talking about but that none/no one
>   wanted to join.

My instinct says *none*, but *no one* has more [Google hits](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22but%20that%20no%20one%20wanted%20to%22&oq=%22but%20that%20no%20one%20wanted%20to%22&gs_l=serp.3...8422.9849.0.10009.8.8.0.0.0.1.270.658.0j3j1.4.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..7.1.265.v_cK0IRzvv0). So I'm confused.

Comment: I get an impression from trying both that "none" would relate to (or be limited to) "my classmates", "no one" is more general, concerns population at large.

Comment: @alexchenco - the other answer (which you did not accepted), correctly describes what is the difference between "none" and "no one" in your context, so I think it is NOT a matter of preference, but a matter what exactly author wanted to say. Consider accepting the better answer (and voting, now you have enough karma points).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is a matter of preference.
As for what sounds natural, I would use "nobody" (esp. since you are referring to people).

Of your two choices, I would prefer *no one*. If I put in *none*, I expect there to be a close link to what it (as a pronoun) refers to, as in "but that none *of them* wanted to join."

Answer (score 2):

**"None"** here means that specifically none of the classmates that were talking about the club wanted to join.

**"No one"** would mean that no one in all of humanity wanted to join.

They are probably equivalent here, so if "none" sounds better to you, go for it.